# Multiple filters on mongoDB mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, networking, mongoengine

For a project on network security that I'm working on, I have a list of every IP in my country (and other relevant fields) in a mongoDB collection.

Like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56674d3d9ee3d40b79167e09"),
    "ip" : "200.6.116.75",
    "server" : "Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
    "date" : "2015-11-23"
}
```

The thing is that now I want to filter on their given ASN (autonomous system number). I do have another collection on which I have the ASN and given IP Blocks.
Here's an example for ASN 6429.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572ba2611c8e25e0a9c44f64"),
    "ASN" : "6429",
    "ip_block" : "200.14.215.0/24"
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572ba2611c8e25e0a9c44f65"),
    "ASN" : "6429",
    "ip_block" : "200.27.0.0/16"
}
```

Now, is there any simple way to make a query filtering on any given ASN?

Concretely, I would like to ask for every IP that matches my given ASN, by asking if the IP matches inside an ip block for such ASN.

Another thing I could do is just ask for the data and not filtering per ASN, and then I could filter things out on python, but it seems to me that such queries should be done by the DBMS.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To have an efficient query parameter for IP lookup, I probably will go to extend the way how IP is stored.

As per normal notation we have just string which cannot be easily extracted to set of 4 integers in mongo,  what do you think to store address in such form:

```
{
   "ip" : "200.6.116.75",
   ipaddress:{a:200, b:6, c:116, d:75}
}
```

Why?

because having netmask we can calculate max and min address.

Let's say we have 'APN: 200.4.0.0/14'

```
Address:   200.4.0.0             11001000.000001 10.01110001.00000000
Netmask:   255.252.0.0 = 14      11111111.111111 00.00000000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.3.255.255           00000000.000000 11.11111111.11111111
=>
Network:   200.4.0.0/14          11001000.000001 00.00000000.00000000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 200.7.255.255         11001000.000001 11.11111111.11111111
HostMin:   200.4.0.1             11001000.000001 00.00000000.00000001
HostMax:   200.7.255.254         11001000.000001 11.11111111.11111110
Hosts/Net: 262142
```

then our query will look:

```
db.col.find({"ipaddress.a":200, 
          $and:{[ {"ipaddress.b": {$gte:3}},{"ipaddress.b": {$lte:7} }}})
```

as this adds an overhead on application side - it will return fully matched result query.

as query generation could be tricky - the `>=` and `<=` operators need to affect group according to bitmask size

```
 1-8    group a
 9-16   group b
 17-23  group c
 24-32  group b
```

Comment: That's a clever way to work around the problem. Thanks!